# AppleScript value for AXURL fails with AppleEvent handler failed

Tags: applescript, itunes, javascript-automation, apple-music

I have been trying to capture a URL in Apple Music (formally iTunes) using AppleScript (JXA JavaScript) but unfortunately when returning the value for an `AXURL` attribute the program.

Am I missing something on converting this `URL` to something useful to return?

### Code (simplified to replicate issue)

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Music"
        open location "itmss://music.apple.com"
        set theWindow to (first window)
        set theBrowser to UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of (group 1) of (group 1) of (splitter group 1) of theWindow
        return value of attribute "AXURL" of theBrowser
    end tell
end tell
```

### Error

```
Error -10000: AppleEvent handler failed.
```

### Console log output

```
Error while returning the result of a script command: the result object...
https://music.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=gb&id=130
...could not be converted to an Apple event descriptor of type 'specifier | number | text | list | record | any | boolean'. 
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingSpecifierDescriptor messages.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingNumberDescriptor messages.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingTextDescriptor messages.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' returned nil when sent -objectSpecifier (is it not overridden?) and there is no coercible type declared for the scripting class 'list'.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingRecordDescriptor messages.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingAnyDescriptor messages.
This instance of the class 'NSURL' doesn't respond to -scriptingBooleanDescriptor messages.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The **URL** on my system is: `https://music.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=us&id=1` That said though, I got it using **Accessibility Inspector**, because `UI element 1` in this reference its `role` is `AXWebArea` and this is a _**black box**_ to basic **AppleScript**.

Comment: `attribute "AXURL"` has been broken for a while, and the error message would seem to indicate that it _does_ contain data, but it can't be converted into an AppleScript type class. It's not specific to _Music_ - it's broken across the board, which also prevents evaluation of attributes collectively if they contain `AXURL` data (but the rest of the attributes can still be evaluated individually).

Comment: @CJK, RE: "(but the rest of the attributes can still be evaluated individually)." -- How? I was under the impression from things I've read that when the `role` is `AXWebArea` it's a _**black box**_ to basic **AppleScript**.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry, I was referring to the general context.  If the `attribute "AXURL"` exists, then other attributes do as well. But generally, as you rightly said, web areas aren't accessible in this manner as they aren't system UI components. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: As an after thought, you could since `UI element 1` is a UI object, you can enumerate the names of other attributes and then reference those individually. I shouldn't think it'll be anything interesting though. `entire contents of UI element 1` will also reveal if there do happen to be any more UI components worthy of investigation.

Comment: Unfortunately any other elements of interest also have `AXURL` values I can not extract.  The above example is simplified version.